# Disable scrolling on a single page ONLY with CSS

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

My website has a landing page where I have our logo and menu. I want to disable scrolling on that page.

I know that

```
body, html {
overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

will do the trick, but it impacts every page on the website.

How do I accomplish this effect on the landing page ONLY?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Does the landing page show for a certain amount of time or close on click? You can probably set up a javascript event to correspond with the CSS you already have. More info would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to `<body>`

```
<body class="specific-page">
</body>
<style>
.specific-page {
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
body, html { 
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: Edit: Sorry, didnt read the last part. Will edit accordingly after finding a solution.